# List site history by domain?

Tags: firefox, history

Is there a way in Firefox to group and count history by domain?  I'd like to see where I've been at a glance and be able to purge it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way in Firefox to group and count history by domain?

Select "By Site".

[image]

You can then select a site, right click and select "Delete" to purge that site:

[image]

Note:

- I am using the "All-in-One Sidebar" and "Classic Theme Restorer" extensions" so the above screenshots may not accurately reflect your Firefox installation.

---

#### Firefox History Function

> Every web page that you visit is logged by Firefox. This is what
>   constitutes your browsing history. If you click on the History text
>   link at the top of the browser you will open a drop-down list of your
>   most recent page visits. You can click on any of those links to return
>   to a page you have recently viewed.
>
> In the same drop-down is an option to “Show in Sidebar”. If you click
>   this link you will open a sidebar on the left of the browser window.
>   This sidebar will group your history for today, yesterday, two days
>   ago an so on. You can expand these groups to see all pages visited in
>   that time frame and then click on any page link to bring up that page
>   in the browser.
>
> By using the “View” button within the sidebar you can also sort and
>   group your History by date within site, site, most visited and last
>   visited.
>
> Sorting by “date and site” is better than “date” alone because it’s
>   easier to see which site you visited on a particular day. The default
>   “by date” option sorts alphabetically within day.
>
> Sorting “by site” is more useful if you just want to see all the pages
>   you have visited for a particular site regardless of when. Both these
>   options are sorted alphabetically by site. However, if you just sort
>   “by site” there is no grouping, just a single list. The “most visited”
>   sort option may give you an idea of which sites are your most popular,
>   but otherwise its usefulness is limited.
>
> The “last visited” option is similar to the default “by date” option except this too is just a long list with the most recent site visited first and then going back in time.

Source [Managing your browsing history in Firefox](http://www.digitalrise.biz/software/managing-your-browsing-history-in-firefox/)

Comment: That's a nice feature.  I was really hoping to be able to sort DESC by visit count.

Comment: It seems that this is no longer possible.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig It still works for me.